# Class of instance contained in Optional

Tags: java, guava

How can I get class of instance contained in Optional if it is absent.
e.g.

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.<String>absent();
```

How can I get String class here. I know the type information is stored internally, is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 4):

> I know the type information is stored internally,

No, it isn't.  Type erasure means that that information is not stored anywhere.  There is no way of getting out information that is not there.